# FPDF some images are printed distorted

Tags: php, image, fpdf

I'm using [tFPDF](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php), which is just [FPDF](http://fpdf.org/) with UTF-8 support. I'm printing documents varying from 40 to 1000 pages. On most of the pages a image is printed. In 99.9% of the times this is just going fine. But sometimes the image gets distored in the PDF, while the image itself is perfect. It happens for both small and large PDF files.

The image is fine for the first 60% of the top, but from that point, it seems that all pixels are shifted to left or right, every row of pixels down.

Below a preview of the images. I made all privacy parts blue, so they are added by me. The image source is a GIF.

Original image that is printed:
[image]

Printed on PDF:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is this a buffer issue? Known FPDF issue?

Comment: Is this only with GIF? Have you tried printing other format images?

Comment: Have not tried other formats, but the gifs are the smallest. I also found out that if I print the image on a new document with just one page, it is also distorted. So it seems that the issue is in the image, although the imageviewer on the computer just shows fine.

Comment: If you can use PNG instead of GIF. A number of image viewers will, as you've discovered, "hide" errors in images and make them look just fine.